# "Ambigous Match Found"

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been trying to re-create BitConverter.GetBytes. However, every value type should be allowed to be passed. The method should then detect its type (Int32, Int16, Byte etc.) and dynamically call the corresponding BitConverter.GetBytes method. My try is to use reflection.
This is what my code looks like:

```
public static class BitConverterExtensions
{

    public static byte[] GetBytes(ValueType obj)
    {
        Type tObj = obj.GetType();
        Type tBitConverter = typeof(BitConverter);
        Type tSelf = typeof(BitConverterExtensions);

        MethodInfo miGetBytes = tBitConverter.GetMethod("GetBytes", new Type[] { tObj });

        byte[] result = (byte[])miGetBytes.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
        return result;
    }

}
```

It works just fine if I pass ints, longs, floats, doubles, bools etc.
The only thing that does not work is passing a byte. If a byte is passed, an AmbiguousMatchException is thrown. However, I cannot see any method with the same signature as

```
byte[] GetBytes(byte)
```

What am I doing wrong and why is it only not working if a byte is passed?
That's how I'm calling the method:

```
byte[] result = BitConverterExtensions.GetBytes((byte)123);
```

Comment: You already got answers, but might I suggest an alternative? `BitConverter.GetBytes((dynamic)obj)` already chooses the appropriate overload in the same way the C# compiler does, assuming one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no overload of `BitConverter.GetBytes()` that accepts a `byte`.  It recognizes this so attempts to promote the `byte` to one that can be used.  However there are many different candidates that could be promoted to thus the ambiguity error.  You might have to special case for that type to just throw the argument into a separate byte array yourself.

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(ValueType obj)
{
    Type tObj = obj.GetType();
    Type tBitConverter = typeof(BitConverter);

    if (tObj == typeof(byte))
        return new byte[] { (byte)obj };

    MethodInfo miGetBytes = tBitConverter.GetMethod("GetBytes", new Type[] { tObj });

    return (byte[])miGetBytes.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've looked everywhere, but I haven't ever thought of the fact that GetBytes doesn't even have an overload that accepts a byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you BitConverter doesn't have a signature for byte, then your code won't work. I'm wandering if you could just do this:

```
if(tobj == typeof(byte))
    return new byte[]{(byte)obj};
```

so you will be returnin a byte[1] with the value (a byte, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is going to make your code inefficient. Since [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) only has 10 overloads, why don’t you just define extension methods for each?

```
public static class BitConverterExtensions
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this bool value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this char value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this double value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this float value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this int value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this long value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this short value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this uint value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this ulong value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this ushort value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
}
```

Then, in your client code:

```
byte[] intBytes = (44).GetBytes();     // gives a 4-byte array
byte[] longBytes = (44L).GetBytes();   // gives an 8-byte array
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about doing it like this. For example I could check the type of the passed parameter and call each method manually. Would probably be faster and also been less of a hassle.

Comment: The above approach might be better because it prevents you from supplying disallowed `ValueType` types – such as `byte` – at compile-time. It would also let you know in advance (e.g. through IntelliSense) what your value is going to get treated as; note the different results for `44` and `44L`.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: I disagree. As I explained in my comment, had the poster used method overloading instead of reflection, the compiler would have immediately prevented them from passing a `byte`, thereby solving their issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because using reflection seems like overkill for such a constrained problem, why not do something like:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesFrom( object o )
{
  Type t = o.GetType() ;
  TypeCode tc = Type.GetTypeCode(t) ;
  byte[] bytes ;

  switch( tc )
  {
  case TypeCode.Boolean  : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (bool)   o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Char     : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (char)   o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Double   : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (double) o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Single   : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (float)  o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Int16    : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (short)  o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Int32    : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (int)    o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Int64    : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (long)   o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.UInt16   : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (ushort) o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.UInt32   : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (uint)   o ) ; break ;
  case TypeCode.UInt64   : bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (ulong)  o ) ; break ;
  // not directly supported by BitConverter, but just for kicks, we'll throw it in.
  case TypeCode.SByte    : bytes = new []{ (byte)o }                   ; break ;
  case TypeCode.Byte     : bytes = new []{ (byte)o }                   ; break ;
  default : throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't get bytes from type {0}" , t.
  }
  return bytes ;
}
```